# How to remove files with a specific extension from a pending changelist?

Tags: version, project, perforce

I accidentally add some .pdb files to a changelist (about 600 files in many folders). I am very beginner at perforce, what I want to know if there is a way to remove all of these files from my current changelist. I tried to create a .p4ignore file with "*.pdb" as its content. Didn't seem to work :/

My changelist: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe7bL.png

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a pending changelist, they aren't in the depot yet so all you need to do is `revert` them.  You can do this one-by-one in P4V, or you can open a terminal window and use the `...` wildcard:

```
p4 revert //....pdb
```

Adding `.pdb` to your `.p4ignore` will prevent future `add` operations from including `.pdb` files as long as the application you're using knows where the `.p4ignore` file is (from the command line this is done by setting `P4IGNORE=.p4ignore`; I don't know how you do it from P4V).

You can also exclude files from your workspace by adding an exclusion mapping to your View (which you edit via either the `p4 client` command or `Edit Workspace...`), like this:

```
View:
    //ExceedreamsDepot/... //your_client_name/...
    -//ExceedreamsDepot/....pdb //your_client_name/....pdb
```

Unlike the `.p4ignore` file this is stored in the server database, so it will apply any time you're using that workspace, regardless of whether `P4IGNORE` is set.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all added .pdb files you can run following command (don't ignore them for now):

```
p4 delete //ExceedreamsDepot/Engine/Binaries/...pdb
```

and them submit that change.

After that action you can add them to P4 ignore to not add them in the future.

Comment: I'm having this return on my terminal: D:\Perforce\DouglasWorkspace>p4 delete //ExceedreamsDepot/Engine/Binaries/...pdb
//ExceedreamsDepot/Engine/Binaries/...pdb - file(s) not on client.